# Cкопировать строки с таблицей отношений N:N

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Подскажите, как скопировать строки из одной таблицы в другую, если обе таблицы имеют по 1 одной таблице отношений N:N.

products_1:

### product_id(PK) | name

70 | валенки

products_2:

### product_id(PK) | name

10 | ватник

Тут при копировании новых строк в products_2 и products_1 получаем PK 11 у строки с name "валенки".

Задача:

есть еще таблицы N:N.

product_categories_1:

### product_id(index) | cat_id

70 | 1

и если просто скопировать

product_categories_2:

### product_id(index) | cat_id

70 | 1

получаем у второй таблицы product_id 70, а нужно 11 (т.е запись должна быть привязана к новых строкам из products_2)

Answer (score 1):

Строки в связующей таблице копировать не надо, после того как добавляете запись в products_2 вам вернется ключ добавленной записи, который вы и добавляете в связующую таблицу.